# Mostrar correctamente las tildes de una consulta a la BD

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Todas las tildes y "Ñ" de las palabras que recibo de esta consulta a la BD no se muestran correctamente.

[image: Resultado]

Parte de código Javascript

```
    $(function(){
    "use strict";
    var ruta = "servicioClientes.php";
    $.ajax({
        url:ruta,
        method:"GET",
        dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,value){
            $("#elementoParaOcultar select").append(
            "<option value="+value.numCliente+">"+value.numCliente+"        "+value.nomCliente+"</option>"
            );
        });
           
        
    });
```

Código en PHP

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rubbercorp");
$rs = mysqli_query($cn,"select * from clientes");
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    $res[]= array_map("utf8_encode",$row);
}
echo json_encode($res);
mysqli_close($cn);
?>
```

Lugar de HTML donde se muestran los valores:

```
<form id="elementoParaOcultar">
      <select id="lenguajes">
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Las columnas de las tablas estan con "utf8_general_ci".
En el  del HTML está incrustado `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
Dudo que el problema esté en el HTML ya que usando otras consultas todo va bien pero con esto no logro encontrar el error.

Comment: Probablemente ya no necesites hacer una modificación desde PHP. Prueba cambiando `$res[]= array_map("utf8_encode",$row);` por `$res[] = $row;`. Y por cierto, [`utf8_encode / utf8_decode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74865684/php-utf8-en-decode-deprecated-what-can-i-use) está deprecado en versiones recientes de PHP.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo cambié por `$res[] = $row;` y ahora funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el `charset` en la conexión a la DB.

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

    echo "Charset Actual: ". mysqli_character_set_name($link)."<br>";

    /* Cámbialo por utf8mb4 */
    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4");

    echo "Charset Nuevo: ". mysqli_character_set_name($link);
    
    // Charset Actual: latin1
    // Charset Nuevo: utf8mb4
```